# Insert different sobject records with single DML in Flows Salesforce

Tags: process-builder, process, flowscreen

Is there a way to insert different sobject records with single DML in flows? I know, in apex we can achieve it by creating a `List<sObject>` but in case of Flows, Can this be achieved by using single DML?

I just want to make sure that instead of specifying DML multiple times , if we can achieve this thru single DML itself in case of Flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix record types in the same collection, so it's not possible to perform DML operations without using Apex. That said, you can create an [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) that accepts several `List<sObject>` variables, and you could combine the DML inside Apex, if you really wanted/needed the extra DML operations to be saved.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox! Looks like apex is the only way to go.